# SKScene Present Scene Transition not Working with SpriteKit Scene in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to get an SKScene presentScene with transition behavior to work.  The presentScene technically works although all I get is the default MoveUp transition behavior.  I am loading a SpriteKit Scene from archive for the scene.  It doesn't seem to matter what I put in for the transition type, I always get the default behavior.  I have debugged to make sure that the transition has a value (i.e., not nil).  I am using iCloud and coreData managed objects, although I don't know how this would impact the scene presentation.  I have included the managed object code in the viewWillAppear.

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GameDelegate {
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var heroCharacter : HeroCharacter!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    presentGameScene()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // access the application managed object context - jwg
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // Persistant Store Changes uses the coordinator
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receivePersistantStoreDidChange", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receivePersistantStoreWillChange:", name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)

    // iCloud notifications using the coordinator
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "receiveICloudChanges:", name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification, object: managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator)
}

// MARK: scenes
func presentGameScene() {
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {

        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        // set target values
        scene.heroCharacter = heroCharacter
        scene.viewDelegate = self

        // this transition is not working
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(10)
        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

The scene code is pretty generic as well

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // access the application managed object context - jwg
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    // Setup physics world's contact delegate
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    // Setup waterfall
    waterfall = self.childNodeWithName(kWaterfallName) as? SKSpriteNode

    // Setup goal
    goal = self.childNodeWithName("goal") as? SKSpriteNode

    // Setup initial camera position
    updateCamera()

    // load texture atlases
    CharacterSprite.loadTextureAtlasArrays()

    var textureAtlasArray = [SKTextureAtlas]()
    textureAtlasArray.append(SKTextureAtlas(named: kIcebergAtlas))

    SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases(textureAtlasArray, withCompletionHandler: { () -> Void in
        #if DEBUG
            print("completed loading atlases")
        #endif
        self.startScene()
    })
}

func updateCamera() {
    if let camera = camera {
        camera.position = CGPoint(x: characterSprite!.position.x, y: characterSprite!.position.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you fading for 10 seconds? Seems long. Also is this the code in your GameViewController?

SKTransitions will only work when transitioning from 1 SKScene to another SKScene. Loading the first scene from your GameViewController will not use a transition since there is technically nothing to transition from.

As a side note, in swift 2 you can get rid of the extension to unarchive the SKScene. You can also just say (if you are using GameScene.sks)

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
...
}
```

Comment: Better to answer the question 1st,  then add in help to the code.  other than that  this is correct,  you are not transitioning from anything in the beginning, your scene is there.  If you need the `SKView` to transition in the beginning,  then you need to look at `UIView` transitioning

Comment: Thank you.  You are correct in that I was trying to transition when presenting the scene from the view controller.  So, attempting to run a transition from the ViewController appears to be the issue.  As a side note, I had 10 seconds in case the transition was happen faster than I was able to see.  As you noted the transition isn't relevant from the ViewController so neither is the time on the transition.

Comment: You are welcome. If you could mark the question as correct please.